# How to differentiate LIST apart from HIERARCHY setting in Apex?

Tags: apex, customsetting, describesobject, schema, reflection

My Apex code needs to **dynamically** reflect on user-defined Custom Settings. But the user could use a List or Hierarchy depending on their needs, so I need to be a bit careful manipulating each type.

It's ok to differentiate Custom Settings from Custom Objects using [`isCustomSetting()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_isCustomSetting) but I'm struggling to differentiate the two types. I had hoped one would be missing `SetupOwnerId` or such:

**List** custom setting has these native fields:

```
CreatedById
CreatedDate
Id
IsDeleted
LastModifiedById
LastModifiedDate
Name
SetupOwnerId
SystemModstamp
```

**Hierarchy** has these native fields... (yep identical, and need to be for sane/happy API)

```
CreatedById
CreatedDate
Id
IsDeleted
LastModifiedById
LastModifiedDate
Name
SetupOwnerId
SystemModstamp
```

I suppose we can see that `Id` == `Name` on an inserted one. Is there better differentiator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found an angle. Starting with the API name:

```
String api = 'MyCustomSetting__c';
```

bit of jiggery pokery...

```
//dynamic object info
Type reflector = Type.forName(api);
SObject sobj = (SObject)reflector.newInstance();
DescribeSObjectResult sobjResult = sobj.getSObjectType().getDescribe();

//some Name field info
SObjectField field = sobjResult.Fields.getMap().get('Name');
DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = field.getDescribe();
Integer length = fieldResult.getLength();
```

...results seem conclusive enough:

```
if (length == 38) {
    //it's a list!
} else if (length == 80) {
    //it's a hierarchy!
}
```

#### (The length of the `Name` field differs)

Comment: Could you not do a bit of round peg square hole and do a `getAll()` execution in a try catch block? Only list custom settings have the getAll method so if it fils or throws an error it is Hierarchy. (Not sure if it even throws an error as I did not try it.. Although your way is elegantly complex :) and not as hackish

Comment: Nice angle @Eric thanks! Struggling to do that dynamically...

Comment: Not sure if it will work dynamically, it just popped into my head so......have not actually tried it which is why comment and no answer :)

Comment: @Eric Fairly certain that throws a compile error, which you cannot catch.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Well shoot, yes it does. Oh well...

Answer (score 2):

Or also, the hierarchy custom setting will have at least one record where the SetupOwnerId is the company Id

`SetupOwnerId = Userinfo.getOrganizationId()`

Comment: This is also the case with List custom settings, at least based on my investigation in `Execute Anonymous`.

Answer (score 0):

Though @mattandneil provides an interesting way to determine dynamically if custom setting has a list or hierarchy type like checking the length of field name

```
Integer length = Type.forName(x).newInstance().getSObjectType().getDescribe().Fields.getMap().get('Name').getDescribe().getLength();

if (length == 38) {
    //it's a list!
} else if (length == 80) {
    //it's a hierarchy!
}
```

were `x` is the name of custom settings, like  `List_Custom_Setting__c` or `Hierarchy_Custom_Setting__c`, I think we should instead open an idea for Salesforce to implement an appropriate method for that like this one
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CZR9QAO and we should vote for it to avoid clumsy code for a such a trivial query